# Odoo. api.onchange doesn't update custom field in screen

Tags: python, odoo, onchange

I'm trying to override an `onchange` function of `account.move.line` model in order to update the value of a custom field I've added to the `account. move` model:

```
class SoftOneInvoiceLine(models.Model):

    _inherit= "account.move.line"

    change_from_user=fields.Boolean('Change by user',default=True)

    @api.onchange('quantity', 'discount', 'price_unit', 'tax_ids')

    def _onchange_price_subtotal(self):
        super(SoftOneInvoiceLine,self)._onchange_price_subtotal()
        for rec in self:
            if (rec.change_from_user):
                rec.move_id.global_discount=0
                rec.move_id.write({'global_discount':0})
                print (rec.move_id," ",rec.move_id.global_discount)
            rec.change_from_user=True
```

The code above, doesn't change the value of the global_discount field in the form when you change one of the 4 fields of account.move.line.

The `_onchange_price_subtotal` functions gets executed, because the print command is displayed in the logs

Why doesn't global_discount new value doesn't reflect on UI?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
rec.move_id.write({'global_discount':0})
```

have you tried update ?

```
rec.move_id.update({'global_discount':0})
```

Also, what you meant by not reflecting in UI ? Is it updated in db table ?